# How to validate enter key in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation, enter

I have following script running on my site. Users have to enter "testnumber" which is 10 character long. There is a length check validation. When users click on submit button my script does work smoothly.

But the problem is that when users press the enter key instead of mouse click, it does not warn the users. How can i change it so that when the users press the enter key this script will give the same message as they click on submit button?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isNumber(n) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }
    function formvalidation(form) {
        var isSubmitting = false;
        var value = document.getElementById('testnumber').value;
        if (value.length == 10) {
            if (isNumber(value)) {
                isSubmitting = true;
            }
        }
        if (isSubmitting) {
            form.submit();
        }
        else {
            alert('testnumber must be at least 10 character.');
            return false;

        }
    }
</script>
```

This is the part of the html code:

```
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <label>
            <div align="left">
                <span class="text7"><strong>enter testnumber:</strong></span>
                <input name="testnumber" type="text" id="testnumber" size="50" value="<%=(testnumber)%>" />
                <input name="search" id="search" type="button" class="normalmail" value="Search" onclick="formvalidation(frmSearch);" />
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </div>
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you have a listener on the submit button? If the user hits enter it will not emulate klick on the submit button but instead will submit the form itself.

Comment: add a `submit` event handler, also: try `return !!(n == +(n));` as your `isNumber` function

Comment: share your html code also

Comment: on which event you calling this function "formvalidation" ?  please try to put it on onsubmit event of a form.

Comment: Also, try using regular expressions for validation: `return value.match(/^\d+{10}$/)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help

```
<from onsubmit="return formvalidation()">
<tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <label>
                            <div align="left">
                                <span class="text7"><strong>enter testnumber:</strong></span>
                                <input name="testnumber" type="text" id="testnumber" size="50" value="<%=(testnumber)%>" />
                                <input name="search" id="search" type="button" class="normalmail" value="Search" onclick="formvalidation(frmSearch);" />
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                <!-- </tr></tr> -->
</form>
```

Your Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isNumber(n) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }
    function formvalidation() {
        var isSubmitting = false;
        var value = document.getElementById('testnumber').value;
        if (value.length > 10 && value.length < 10) {
            alert('testnumber must be at least 10 character.');
            return false
        }
        else if (isSubmitting) {
            return true
        }
        else {            
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```